# How to plot 3d spheres with "Glossy color" in matplotlib (Python), like the Fig. 1 below?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter3d

I have a dataset with 4 columns (x, y, z, size), and want to produce a scatter plot of spheres in 3D like the following Fig.1. What I have been able to produce so far is shown in Fig.2. The spheres are not smooth and the color is not shiny like what I want.

[Fig.1 (what I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijb0l.png)

[Fig.2 (what I have produced so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2S8A.png)

Any ideas on how to make the spheres look smooth and colored shiny?
Thank you.

The code I am using is given below:

```py
def drawSphere(xCenter, yCenter, zCenter, r):
    #draw sphere
    u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
    x=np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
    y=np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
    z=np.cos(v)
    # shift and scale sphere
    x = r*x + xCenter
    y = r*y + yCenter
    z = r*z + zCenter
    return (x,y,z)

# draw a sphere for each data point
amplifier = 2500 # to magnify the spheres
for i, (xi,yi,zi,ri) in enumerate(zip(location['x'],location['y'],location['z'],location['amp']/amplifier)):
    (xs,ys,zs) = drawSphere(xi,yi,zi,ri)
    ax.plot_surface(xs, ys, zs, color = cmap(norm(location['amp'][i])), edgecolor='none', alpha=1)
```

Comment: Matplotlib only has limited 3D support. You could try Mayavi instead.

Comment: The idea is to increase the number of discretization points for the sphere and then setup a light source. Doing so, will slow down thing quite significantly because Matplotlib doesn't have a great 3D support. You can try a different library, for example Plotly or K3D jupyter.